# add a link in a text view and open this link on navigator

Tags: android, hyperlink, textview

i take a string from my ressource strings.xml and put the string in a TextView.

In strings.xml :

```
<string name="description">Hello please look into <a href="http://www.webtour.dk">www.webtour.dk</a></string>
```

In main.xml :

```
<TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/description"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
```

I got this result good result,www.webtour.dk appear as a link. But when i click on the link i got nothing!!! no navigator is launched??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use [Linkify](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aautoLink) to look for web sites automatically:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:text="@string/description"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Then take the html out of your text:

```
<string name="description">Hello please look into www.webtour.dk</string>
```